# Stop Java/TomCat adding Port to URL on redirect to login

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I've got a Java app running on a TomCat server on EC2.

When the app redirects to login when you try and access a page that isn't logged in, it redirects home '/'

```
    protected void redirectLogin(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    String req = request.toString();
    String path = req.substring(req.indexOf('/'), req.indexOf(')'));
    getSession(request).setLoginRedirect(path);
    redirectHome();
}

protected void redirectHome() throws IOException {
    redirect("/");
}
```

When this happens, the port number gets added to the URL i.e. admin.example.com:9081, and any further activity in the app is adversely affected by having this in the URL (things not saving etc).

Is there anyway to stop the port number getting added?